# Can you attach 2 coaxial leads to a single TV antenna

Tags: antenna, tv

I would like to hookup 6 TV's to one antenna. The largest splitters only have 4 outputs. Can I run 2 leads from the same antenna each to a 3 way splitter?

Comment: You should connect one splitter with two outputs to the antenna. Then take two splitters with 2 outputs and connect their inputs two the outputs of the first spliiter. You get 6 outputs altogether. Active splitters with amplification might be necessary.

Comment: If you want to feed that many receivers from a single antenna, you might want to use a [distribution amplifier](https://support.channelmaster.com/hc/en-us/articles/200383705-What-Is-a-Distribution-Amplifier-and-Do-I-Need-One-)

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a splitter from antenna to two cables. The splitter matches the characteristic impedance of the antenna to each of the coax cables. Tying two cables directly to the antenna screws up the impedance match and can result in signal reflections which severely degrades the signal integrity.

Do note that a 1 to 2 splitter reduces available signal power to each output cable to about half the input signal power. Wider splitters reduce even more. Cascading splitters correspondingly reduces target signal power even more. For example if you cascaded a 1->2 to another 1 -> 2 splitter the signal at the output of the second splitter would be only about one quarter the input power level.

Using splitters is Ok if you have a good strong signal from the antenna. If you are in a weak signal area you should consider using an RF signal distribution device which includes amplification and buffered outputs.